# Verificar se o imput é Int em uma interface no netBeans

Tags: netbeans, jframe

Boa noite! eu estou fazendo um programa com interface no NetBeans. Eu preciso comparar se a entrada de dados no campo de texto onde se deve dizer qual a quantidade é uma String pois só queria deixar disponível entrada de valores Int! Queria alguma saber se existe algum comando de comparação pra tal. Já pesquisei mas não encontrei nenhum resultado de fato. Se puderem me ajudar, eu agradeço! Segue o código do botão que adiciona no banco de dados os valores digitados.

```
private void cad_cadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    Produtos produto = new Produtos();
    produto.setFabricante(cad_fabricante.getText());
    produto.setModelo(cad_modelo.getText());
    produto.setValor(Integer.parseInt(cad_valor.getText()));
    produto.setEstoque(Integer.parseInt(cad_qtd.getText()));

    if(cad_fabricante.getText().isEmpty() || cad_modelo.getText().isEmpty() || cad_valor.getText().isEmpty()||cad_qtd.getText().isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos.");
    }else if(--------->A COMPARAÇÃO ENTRARIA AQUI <-----------)){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Os Campos VALOR e ESTOQUE devem ser preenchidos com números.");

    }else{
    ProdutosDAO dao = new ProdutosDAO();
    dao.AdicionarPeca(produto);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Produto " + cad_fabricante.getText()+ " adicionado com sucesso!" );

    }
    cad_fabricante.setText("");
    cad_modelo.setText("");
    cad_valor.setText("");
    cad_qtd.setText("");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pensando em condições de entrada no java, como podemos verificar se um determinado valor é Integer?

```
Integer.parseInt(valor)
```

é claro que java é uma linguagem fortemente tipada e isso ajuda em entradas, mas se tratando de usuários sabemos que podemos solicitar uma entrada por ex.: "digite um número" e o usuário digita "UM" assim por diante...

em relação a sua pergunta podemos fazer essa conversão, mas ela irá lançar uma excessão, nesse caso podemos utilizar expressões regulares.

eu criei a classe Product
com seus respectivos atributos.

```
public class Product {

    private String fabricante;
    private String modelo;
    private Integer valor;
    private Integer qtd;

    public Product(String fabricante, String modelo, Integer valor, Integer qtd) {
        this.fabricante = fabricante;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.qtd = qtd;
    }

    public Product() {}

    //get and setters

}
```

Logo em seguida criei uma classe para testarmos essa classe, onde eu utilizei uma condição com expressão regular.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestProduct {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String valor = null;
        Integer val = null;
        boolean condicao = true;
        Product product = new Product();

         product.setFabricante(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Qual fabricante"));
         product.setModelo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Qual modelo?"));

         try {
             valor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o valor em numeral");
             while(condicao) {
                 if(valor.matches("[0-9]*")) {
                     val = Integer.parseInt(valor);
                     condicao = false;
                 }
                 else {
                     valor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o valor em numeral");
                 }
             }

         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
         }


        product.setValor(val);

        System.out.println(product.getFabricante());
        System.out.println(product.getValor());
    }

}
```

daí no final basta fazer suas inserções utilizando a JPA.